# Fingernail can scratch cooking board = too soft?

Tags: cutting-boards

I was using a lot of elbow grease to sand down my cheap cutting board to remove the deep grooves caused by my knife. Then I questioned myself if it's even worth the effort and just get a new better quality cutting board. I recently realized can scratch my cutting board with just my fingernail. Is that sign that it's too soft?

[American Test Kitchen recommends the Proteak cutting board](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiCNB0fId0U) because it's not too hard or soft. I will get this board if it's truly worth the money.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Was the board wet when you scratched it?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not all that clear what your question really is, I'm going to go with the question in the title:

If you can mark your dry cutting board with a fingernail, the wood is softer than you want for a good cutting board.  In fact, your cutting board would need to be a very soft pine, fir, or similar wood to be that soft, none of which are ideal for cutting boards.  This explains why you have "deep grooves".

I own a teak cutting board (it was a gift), and I don't know that I'd recommend it.  Teak is hard enough to dull my knives faster than a softer hardwood like beech or maple would (bamboo has the same issue).  Beyond that, there is quite a bit of debate about which wood is best for cutting boards and instead of trying to reproduce it here I'm going to give you some reading:

- [Tasty Kitchn's Best Wood for Cutting Boards](https://www.tastykitchenn.com/kitchen-supplies/best-wood-for-cutting-board/)
- [Serious Eats Recommendations on Cutting Boards](https://www.seriouseats.com/2019/07/best-wooden-cutting-boards.html)
- [Brooklyn Butcher Block's opinion on various woods](https://www.brooklynbutcherblocks.com/blogs/news/best-wood-for-a-cutting-board)

Comment: There's definite downside to knife-dulling bamboo. I tried one, and quickly went back to making my own boards out of maple with cherry striping. A boa4d that's too soft will likely have sanitary issues, as bacteria find good homes in all those scratches knives, and finger-nails make.